Help finding CDF of $Z$ given $ Z = \frac Y X$
Can anyone help me solve the problem below using integrals without resorting to graphical figures ?

Question:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables that are uniformly
distributed on the interval $[0, 1]$. What is the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of the random variable $Z = \frac Y X?$

Correct answer is:


My faulty attempt:

Thank you.

Please add your thoughts/what you tried to this question. "Solve that problem for me" questions usually get downvoted and/or flagged here quickly.

Hi @Tina, I have added it as you've wished. Thank you.

Thats great! Unfortunetly pictures are best to avoid either, you should use mathjax instead. I think it would be best if you read this post "how to ask a good question" to make your post a high quality post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992

We can safely ignore the instance where $X=0$ as $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ is a Lebesgue null set. Now we evaluate the probability of $P(Y\leq zX)$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent we know that their joint probability distribution factorizes and we can compute that event as:
$$P(Y\leq zX) = \int\limits_0^1 P(Y\leq zx) \mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_0^1 \mathbf{1}_{\max(0,\min(1,xz))}(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
For values of $z<0$ we have that $zx$ is negative thuts $\min(1,xz)$ is always negative and the outer function maxes out at $0$. Or more plainly: Both $X$ and $Y$ are positive almost surely, thus $\frac XY$ are postive almost surely, thus the probability of $\frac XY$ to be negative is $0$.
Now evaluate the integral for $1\leq z\leq 0$ then $0\leq xz\leq 1$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Thus we integrate $\int_0^1 xz \mathrm dx = \frac z2$.
Now evaluate the integral for $z>1$. Then we split the integral in a part for where $xz\leq 1$ and a part where $xz>1$.
First Part:
$$\int_0^{\frac 1z} xz\mathrm dx = \frac 1{2z^2}z=\frac 1{2z}$$
Second Part:
$$\int_{\frac 1z}^1 1\mathrm {d} x = 1 - \frac 1z$$.
Summing up: $1 - \frac 1{2z}$.
The combined function is continuous at $0$ and $1$.

Thank you very much but I have trouble following some of your steps. Could you please explain further how you obtained $\mathbf{1}_{\max(0,\min(1,xz))}(x)$ ?

Preliminary comment:
Whereas Snake707's answer is perfectly fine, I'm going to introduce another answer which uses the majestic power of Dirac's delta function $\delta(x)$. I'll leave the link to Wiki for any further references you should decide to search for, but the property is as follows: given a random variable $X$ and the differenctiable transform $Y=g(X)$, the resulting random variable distribution can be found by calculating:
$$
f_Y(y) =\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_X(x)\delta\left(y-g(x)\right) \, \mathbb{d}x
$$
Proceeding to our case:
As it happens, in our case we have the following setting: given i.i.d. random variables $X, Y\sim\mathbb{U}_{[0,1]}$ and the transformation: $Z=g(X,Y)=\frac{Y}{X}$, we get
$$
f_Z(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\delta\left(z-g(x,y)\right) \, \mathbb{d}x \mathbb{d}y = \int_{[0;1]^2}\delta\left(z-\frac{y}{x}\right) \, \mathbb{d}x \mathbb{d}y
$$
where in the second equation we utilised the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and distributed over the unit square.
Now, introduce the variable change:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{}
u={y}/{x} \\
v=xy
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and the Jacobian:
$$
|J|=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
\end{array}
\right] = \frac{1}{2u}
$$
Hence:
$$
f_Z(z)= \int_{\mathbb{B}}\frac{\delta(z-u)}{2u} \, \mathbb{d}u \mathbb{d}v
$$
where $\mathbb{B}$ is a domain over which $(v, u)$ are distributed. If you draw the mapping of the square under this variable change in $(v, u)$-coordinates, you'll get the shape in the first quadrant that is restricted by the curves $u=v$ and $u=\frac{1}{v}$. All that's left is to integrate the integral above over this domain and use the property of the delta.
First, consider the area: $u \in [0; 1]$, $v\in[0, u]$:
$$
f_Z(z) \Bigg|_{u \in [0; 1], v \in[0, u]} 
= \int_{[0; 1]}\frac{\delta(z-u)}{2u} \, \mathbb{d}u \int_{0}^{u}\mathbb{d}v 
= \int_{[0; 1]}\frac{\delta(z-u)}{2u} u \, \mathbb{d}u = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(z-u) \mathbf{1}_{[0;1]} \, \mathbb{d}u = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[0;1]}
$$
Second, the area: $u \in [1; \infty]$, $v \in [0, \frac{1}{u}]$:
$$
f_Z(z) \Bigg|_{u \in [1; \infty], v \in [0, \frac{1}{u}]} 
= \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta(z-u)}{2u} \, \mathbb{d}u \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{u}}\mathbb{d}v 
= \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta(z-u)}{2u} \frac{1}{u} \, \mathbb{d}u 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\delta(z-u)}{2u^2} \mathbf{1}_{[1;\infty]} \, \mathbb{d}u = \frac{1}{2z^2} \mathbf{1}_{[1;\infty]}
$$
Which finally makes it:
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[0;1]} + \frac{1}{2z^2} \mathbf{1}_{[1;\infty]} = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0             ,& z \le 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}   ,& 0 \le z \le 1 \\
\frac{1}{2z^2},& z \ge 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Finally, to find the CDF of $Z$, we need to integrate this function:
$$
\mathbb{P}(Z \le z) = \int_{-\infty}^{z}f_Z(t) \, \mathbb{d}t =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0            ,& z \le 0 \\
\frac{z}{2}      ,& 0 < z \le 1 \\
1-\frac{1}{2z} ,& z > 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Where we've utilised the fact that for any CDF: $F(\infty)=1$ and $F(-\infty)=0$.

It is possible to write down the answer to this problem without doing any explicit integration if one is willing to look at a graph, but since the OP explicitly does not want to even consider looking at a graph, and so here goes $\ldots$
For $0 < z \leq 1,$
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &= P(Z \leq z)\\
&= P\left(\frac YX \leq z\right)\\
&= P(Y \leq zX)\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{zx} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{zx} 1 \,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx\\
&=  \int_0^1 zx\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \frac z2.
\end{align}
For $z > 1,$
\begin{align}
1-F_Z(z) &= P(Z > z)\\
&= P\left(\frac YX > z\right)\\
&= P(Y > zX)\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{y/z} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{y/z} 1 \,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy\\
&=  \int_0^1 y/z \,\mathrm dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2z}.
\end{align}
This gives
$$F_Z(z) = \begin{cases}0, & z<0,\\\frac z2, & 0 \leq z < 1,\\1 - \frac{1}{2z}, & z \geq 1,
\end{cases}$$
exactly as in the other answers.
So what's the graphical method that the OP does not like? Well, the random point $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit square, and so for any region $\mathcal A$ in the square,  $P((X,Y) \in \mathcal A) = {\text{Area}(\mathcal A})$.  Thus

For $z \in [0,1]$, $P(Z \leq z)$, the probability that $(X,Y)$ lies in the right triangular region with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,z)$ of area $\frac z2$, is just $\frac z2$. That is, $F_Z(z) = \frac z2, 0 < z < 1.$

For $z > 1$,
$P(Z > z)$, the probability that $(X,Y)$ lies in the right triangular region with vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (z^{-1},1)$ of area $\frac{1}{2z}$, is just $\frac{1}{2z}$, and so $F_Z(z) = 1 - \frac{1}{2z}$ for $z > 1$.


Look Ma! No explicit integration, just finding areas of triangles using grade-school level geometry.
